# how to find open source monolith codebases?

Tags: github, design-patterns, architecture, monolithic

I need to find monolith architecture codebases to make a research. Preferably in Python or JavaScript. Do you have a suggestion on how to find these codebases?

I currently searched for this topic on Github: https://github.com/topics/monolith

But it doesn't have many options.

Comment: Look for open source eCommerce projects. Most of the popular eCommerce projects I've seen (in C# anyway) are monoliths and I suspect it's the same for JavaScript and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these repositories:

> [Monolithic model-view-controller full-stack web application](https://github.com/JacobGrisham/Finance-Full-Stack-Web-App-using-Flask-and-SQL) built with
> Python, Flask, SQL Alchemy, MySQL, Jinja, and Bootstrap. Application
> Server hosted on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu, Gunicorn, and Nginx. MySQL
> Database on AWS RDS. Redis hosted on AWS Elasticache. CI/CD with
> Jenkins and AWS CodeDeploy

and:

> [This is one of my projects under Udacity's Cloud Native Application
> Architecture Nanodegree](https://github.com/zarexalvindaria/udaconnect). In this project, I have refactored
> Udaconnect's monolithic architecture into a microservice architecture
> using several message passing techniques. First, I have reviewed the
> application and chose the best message passing techniques suitable for
> each micr…

and:

> [SFA-API is the prototype of an API with two different architectures](https://github.com/alicevillar/sfa_api)
> (monolothic architecture and a microservice architecture).